# Audio/Sound issue in agora voice call

Tags: android, voice, agora.io

In the ongoing call, some user experience the issue that **voice stops** coming and going from device. and **speaker on/off** also doesn't work, **even leave channel doesn't help**. Then we need to kill and reopen the app.

I'm using **agora voice sdk version- 3.3.0**

We have not found any error code or warning code in this case. so kindly help us on this.

Comment: `so kindly help us on this` how ? you haven't posted any relevant code for anyone to review, best we could do is guess. you need to add enough details to recreate the problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. But then I upgraded to 4.5 and now its working fine